# Querying object using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object with nested attributes, and some of those have a 'selected' property. Im trying to get those values using underscore, and even though I succeeded the code doesnt look very readable:

```
_.chain(config)
  .pairs()
  .map(function(e) {
    var s = {};

    s[e[0]] = _.chain(e[1])
      .filter(function(e) {
        if (e.selected) {
          return e;
        }
      })
      .pluck('name')
      .join(',')
      .value();

    return s;
  })
  .flatten()
  .filter(function(e) {
    if (_.values(e)[0] !== '') {
      return e;
    }
  })
  .reduce(_.extend)
  .value();
```

This is the configuration object that I'm using:

```
var config = {
 'property__1': [
   {name: 'test1', selected: 1},
   {name: 'test2'}
 ],
 'property__2': [
   {name: '0'},
   {name: '1', selected: 1},
   {name: '2'},
   {name: '3'},
   {name: '4', selected: 1}
 ],
 'property__3': [
   {name: '0'},
   {name: '1'},
   {name: '2', selected: 1},
   {name: '3'}
 ],
 'property__4': [
   {name: 'test1'},
   {name: 'test2', selected: 1}
 ]
};
```

And would like to get the following output:

```
{
  "property__1": "test1",
  "property__2": "1,4",
  "property__3": "2",
  "property__4": "test2"
}
```

Is there anything else that I could do to refactor it, or any properties that Im not aware of that might be useful to make this piece of code more readable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points:

- A `filter` callback is supposed to return a boolean value, not object that should be collected. It would be just `return e.selected == 1`, or even just returning `1` vs `undefined`.
- I'm not sure what the `.flatten()` is required for
- `_.values(e)[0]` looks especially awful. You should consider filtering *before* making the objects.

I'd go with

```
_.reduce(config, function(s, e, k) {
    var vals = _.filter(e, _.property("selected"));
    if (vals.length)
        s[k] = _.pluck(vals, "name").join();
    return s;
}, {});
```

<sub>Admittedly, the test for the `.length` is different from your string check for empty `.name`s, but I guess it is what you actually wanted</sub>

Of course, you could stretch that to

```
_.chain(config)
  .pairs()
  .map(function(p) {
      return [p[0], _.filter(p[1], _.property("selected"))];
  }).filter(function(p) {
      return p[1].length;
  }).map(function(p) {
      return [p[0], _.chain(p[1]).pluck("name").join().value()];
  })
  .object()
  .value();
```

… which is more like your original one, but that only looks lengthy not better.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using jQuery each loop. the code is much simpler and readable.

```
var output = {}
//first each loop will iterate over property__1,property__2,...
$.each(config, function(propertyName) {
    //here 'this' will refer to the array that 'property__1' holds, 
    //and the next each loop will iterate over this array.
    $.each(this, function(){ 
        //here 'this' will refer to the element of the array,
        //for example object {name: 'test1', selected: 1}
        if(typeof this.selected !== 'undefined'){ //check if 'selected' property is present
            //if present then map required value on propertyName
            if(output[propertyName]){
                output[propertyName] += ',' + this.name; //append comma seperated if already mapped
            } else {        
                output[propertyName] = this.name; //map directly if for the first time
            }
        }
    });
});
console.log(output);
```

Let me know this helps you :)

Comment: Why would you use jQuery instead of a plain loop? Btw, imperative style might be more "readable" (lengthier), but is usually not considered simpler.